# How to extract xml string to make a new colums in sql using XQuery/XPath?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, xquery, extract

Hi I have here my code for now and Im not getting the result correctly using this codes;

```
Declare @txt varchar(max) = (
    select audit_val from AuditTable 
    where audit_val like '%update_dt%' 
    and audit_val like '%PEK150700019-001%')

Declare @xml XML = CONVERT(XML,@txt)

SELECT 
    @xml.value('(/i/@guest_id)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as guest_id
    , @xml.value('(/i/@updated_by)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as updated_by
    , @xml.value('(/i/@update_dt)[1]', 'datetime') as update_dt
```

what I am getting is null values and it says it returned more than one value, 
using select top 1 will do, but **I need to extract all of the string needed on that column from the table rows, can someone help me how to fix this ? thanks in advance :)**

Note** heres a sample output;

```
=================================================================
|guest_id          |   updated_by     |     update_dt           |
|==================|==================|=========================|
|PEK150700019-001  |  sherwin         |  2015-08-11T13:59:09.550|
|------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
```

Comment: "returned more than one value" might be your first section where you are setting `@txt`. Put an `ORDER BY `and `TOP 1` in there. Before asking any question you should isolate where the error actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
declare @auditTable TABLE(audit_val varchar(1000))
insert into @auditTable values('<i guest_id="PEK150700019-001" updated_by="sherwin" update_dt="2015-08-11T13:59:09.550" place_birth="SHANGHAI"/>')

select 
    (CONVERT(XML,audit_val)).value('(/i/@guest_id)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as guest_id
    , (CONVERT(XML,audit_val)).value('(/i/@updated_by)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as updated_by
    , (CONVERT(XML,audit_val)).value('(/i/@update_dt)[1]', 'datetime') as update_dt
from @auditTable 
where audit_val like '%update_dt%' 
      and audit_val like '%PEK150700019-001%'
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/3461)</kbd>**

Use *`XML` data type* in the first place for storing *XML data*. That way you can avoid having to do multiple time casting varchar to XML which may improve the query performance.

**output :**

```
|         guest_id | updated_by |                update_dt |
|------------------|------------|--------------------------|
| PEK150700019-001 |    sherwin | August, 11 2015 13:59:09 |
```

Comment: @Wane If you could provide a representative example of the actual XML you're dealing with in the first place, that would allow people to give the most appropriate suggestion in the first shot :)

Comment: That won't help. My previous comment simply meant, if your actual XML has multiple elements, then you should've provided an example that contains multiple elements.

Comment: I just realized that what i am saying are nonesense :D thanks a lot for the Help :) you're the best ! thanks so much !!

Comment: **SORRY I HAVE TO DELETE MY PREVIOUS COMMENT @har07 , I RECOMMEND THIS AS THE BEST ANSWER :)**